# Can't get rid of space over columns

Tags: html, space

I have tried for days to figure this out and I'm at a loss.  I plugged it into jsFiddle and there is no space, but on the website...there is.  What is causing this?  Can anyone see my problem?

```
<a href="http://130.111.132.29/betasite/projects/>Click Here for Site</a>
```

There should be no space between the paragraph at the top and the columns....

Answer (score 0):

you could use tool like firebug to inspect what generate this space.

Comment: i'm not sure what space you are talking about, please provide anotated screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You have included a

```
<p> blabla 
</p>
```

in your proj_text div, so there is a blank line before your column. You can remove it.

Comment: I removed it and tried <span> and a <div> but nothing changed.